# Search View On Sqlite Database Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-search

I am working on application, that exists Sqlite Database. What I have done to implement the search on sqlite database using list, I have implemented the like query and I came to know; The searchview is not searching data from sqlite...

Here is my Sqlite File....

```
    public List<GetSetClientsDetail> SearchClientsData() {

    String[] columns = {
            fname,
            route,
            cnic,
            lname,
            contact
    };

    String sortOrder = fname + " ASC";

    List<GetSetClientsDetail> clientlist = new ArrayList<GetSetClientsDetail>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            table_poducts_records,
            new String[] { fname, route, cnic, lname, contact},
            fname + " LIKE '%" + fname + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GetSetClientsDetail clientsDetail = new GetSetClientsDetail();

            clientsDetail.setFNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fname)));
            clientsDetail.setROUTE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(route)));
            clientsDetail.setCNIC(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cnic)));
            clientsDetail.setLNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(lname)));
            clientsDetail.setCONTACT(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contact)));
            clientlist.add(clientsDetail);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return clientlist;
}
```

Here is my viewpage class of search where I have implemented search..

```
public class Clients extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerViewClients;
Button btnAll;
SearchView searchViewclient;
ClientRecyclerAdapter clientRecyclerAdapter;
List<GetSetClientsDetail> listclients;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.clients, container, false);

    btnAll=view.findViewById(R.id.searchallclients);
    recyclerViewClients=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewallclients);
    searchViewclient=view.findViewById(R.id.searchclient);
    listclients = new ArrayList<>();

    clientRecyclerAdapter = new ClientRecyclerAdapter(listclients,recyclerViewClients);
    recyclerViewClients.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewClients.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator()); //multi copy paste!
    recyclerViewClients.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerViewClients.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewClients.setAdapter(clientRecyclerAdapter);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    searchViewclient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SearchSQliteClientData();
        }
    });

    btnAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getClientFromSqlite();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void SearchSQliteClientData() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listclients.clear();
            listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.SearchClientsData());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void getClientFromSqlite() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listclients.clear();
            listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllClientsData());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

}

What I want to do is As I press A on searchview; It brings all data related to a or If I press a letter It bring that data in the list I have Implemented..

[image: Cannot Resolve Method Query]

Comment: try to print query that fires..and execute it sqlite browser wil get more idea

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment a little bi

Comment: do something like this         sql = " SELECT fname, route, cnic, lname, contact  FROM table_poducts_records WHERE fname + " LIKE '%" + fname + "%'" ;
       cursor  = db.rawQuery(sql, null); and try to print this query

Comment: working on It to implement this query

Comment: cannot resolve symbol LIKE this time

Comment: sql=" SELECT fname, route, cnic, lname, contact FROM "+ table_poducts_records+" WHERE fname " + " LIKE '" + fname + "%'";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193670/discussion-between-aliza-shah-and-android-user).

Comment: Will the data be like the column's name? Assume that the fname column is called fname then using  `fname + " LIKE '%" + fname + "%'"` will return rows where the fname column contains values that include **fname**.

Comment: Yes the column names are same

Comment: All the data has the column name in it?

Comment: what query prints?

Comment: Nothing this Time; It is showing error on query Like I have updated my question with the Image of Qery Error

Comment: its db.rawQuery(sql,null) and sql=sql=" SELECT fname, route, cnic, lname, contact FROM "+ table_poducts_records+" WHERE fname " + " LIKE '" + fname + "%'";

Comment: the query method does not take raw SQL hence why the editor error, it takes parameters as per [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String))

Comment: Then what I do with cursor; because the cursor is used for setting the names and other attributes to the ist

Answer (score 0):

As an example

change `public List<GetSetClientsDetail> SearchClientsData()`

to

```
public List<GetSetClientsDetail> SearchClientsData(String mysearchstring)
```

- this allows the search argument to be passed to the method from the caller

Then change :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            table_poducts_records,
            new String[] { fname, route, cnic, lname, contact},
            fname + " LIKE '%" + fname + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
```

to

```
String[] whereargs = new String[]{"%" + mysearchstring + "%"}; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            table_poducts_records,
            new String[] { fname, route, cnic, lname, contact},
            fname + " LIKE ?", //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
            whereargs, //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            null, null, null); //<<<<<<<<<< 3 nulls instead of 4 (as whereargs has replaced first null)
```

- this uses the search argument passed to the method in the LIKE clause protecting against SQL Injection

As a test try :-

```
 listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.SearchClientsData("A")); //<<<<<<<<<< look for all with A anywhere in the fname column
```

## Working example

The following is a working example based upon the code in the question but simplified for convenience.

The core change is two fold as, the above code is in the database helper **DatabaseHelper.java** as per :-

That is the SearchClientData method is :-

```
public List<GetSetClientsDetail> SearchClientsData(String mysearchstring) {

    String[] columns = {
            fname, route, cnic, lname, contact
    };

    String sortOrder = fname + " ASC";
    List<GetSetClientsDetail> clientlist = new ArrayList<GetSetClientsDetail>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] whereargs = new String[]{"%" + mysearchstring + "%"}; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            table_poducts_records,
            new String[]{fname, route, cnic, lname, contact},
            fname + " LIKE ?",
            whereargs,
            null, null, sortOrder, null
    );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GetSetClientsDetail clientsDetail = new GetSetClientsDetail();

            clientsDetail.setFNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fname)));
            clientsDetail.setROUTE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(route)));
            clientsDetail.setCNIC(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cnic)));
            clientsDetail.setLNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(lname)));
            clientsDetail.setCONTACT(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contact)));
            clientlist.add(clientsDetail);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return clientlist;
}

public List<GetSetClientsDetail> getAllClientsData() {
    return SearchClientsData("");
}
```

- Note the freebie getAllClientsData which just uses the SearchClientData method passing "", which will select all rows.

The other core change is that instead of relying upon the SearchView's **OnClickListener**  which may well get called due to the Views other Listener's stealing the focus-ability.

The SearchView's **setOnQueryTextListener** has been utilised. This allows the text to be passed to the SearchClientsData.

For convenience this example utilises an ArrayAdapter and the stock Simple_List_Item1 layout and does the work on the main thread and of activity.

The Activity code used was :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listviewClients;
    Button btnAll;
    ArrayAdapter mSCA;
    SearchView searchViewclient;
    List<GetSetClientsDetail> listclients;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAll=this.findViewById(R.id.searchallclients);
        listviewClients=this.findViewById(R.id.clients);
        searchViewclient=this.findViewById(R.id.searchclient);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeData();
        manageListView("");

        searchViewclient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                manageListView("zzz");
            }
        });
        searchViewclient.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                manageListView(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        btnAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                manageListView("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void manageListView(String searchArgument) {
        listclients =  databaseHelper.SearchClientsData(searchArgument);
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listclients);
            listviewClients.setAdapter(mSCA);
        } else {
            mSCA.clear();
            mSCA.addAll(listclients);
            mSCA.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void addSomeData() {
        databaseHelper.add("Albert","001","123456789","Smith","someone");
        databaseHelper.add("Freda","001","123456789","Jones","someone");
        databaseHelper.add("Mike","002","0987654321","Allenby","him");
    }



    /*
    private void SearchSQliteClientData() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                listclients.clear();
                listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.SearchClientsData());
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    private void getClientFromSqlite() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                listclients.clear();
                listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllClientsData());
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    */
}
```

- The addSomeData method does as it says adds some testing data. The commented out code is original but unused code.

## Result

When first run (not really the 1st, rather after a number of runs BUT freshly started, hence plenty of data) :-

[image]

Typing **a** or **A**  and all the Mike's disappear

[image]

and so on, the list is instantly adjusted according to the text entered in the search field. Clicking the ALL button re-displays all.

Comment: This all brings nothing while writing something on searchview